# Handling plugins with configuration with Ninject

Tags: ninject

I'm writing an application where various bits of business logic can sit in separate assemblies, then those bits are used to build an object expecting two interfaces, something like this:

```
public interface ISubjectSource {}
public interface IStudySource {}

public class Worker
{
   public Worker(ISubjectSource subjectSource, IStudySource studySource)
   {
     ....
   }
}
```

The seperate assemblies can contain various implementations of `ISubjectSource` and `IStudySource`. Then along with a config file:

```
"Study1":{  
    "assemblies":["Compare.Sql.dll"],   
    "mappingSource":"Compare.Sql.SqlSubjectSource,Compare.Sql",
    "studySource":"Compare.Sql.SqlStudySource,Compare.Sql", 
}
```

Which describes what is needed to build to worker for "Study1". My problem arrives when the various sources have their own dependencies (e.g. the Sql Sources take an interface that handles creating a connection whose connection string might come from different files).

So, my question boils down to: How do I tell Ninject that when I create a worker for study1, be sure it gets these objects, but when I create a worker for Study2, it gets this other set of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we do:

We've got an interface `IPlugin`, with an identifier and an enumerable of modules.

```
public interface IPlugin
{
  string Identification { get; }

  IEnumerable<Type> Modules { get; }
}
```

The Types in Modules must all be inheriting from `NinjectModule`. `Identification` is what you refer to in your configuration, like "i want to use plugin SQLStudySource" or "i want to use plugin FileStudySource".

Then we are using https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions to bind all IPlugin implementations from a specific set of assemblies (like all assemblies in the plugin folder):

```
this.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesInPath("foo")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<IPlugin>()
            .BindTo<IPlugin>());
```

Next you activate plugins (or rather their modules, respectively), according to configuration:

```
IEnumerable<Type> activatedPluginModules = kernel
  .GetAll<IPlugin>()
  .Where(plugin => configuration.ActivatedPluginIdentifications.Contains(plugin.Identification)
  .SelectMany(x => x.Modules)
  .Distinct();

foreach(Type module in activatedPluginModules) 
{
  kernel.Load(module);
}
```

That's about it.